# Why SASS @mixin not working in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, css, sass

For the first time, I was trying to implement SASS following it's [tutorial](http://sass-lang.com/guide) in my [ASP.NET MVC web project](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

The code which I'm trying to implement is for using `@mixin`

```css
@mixin global {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  outline: none;
}
*:link,
*:focus,
*:visited,
*:hover,
*:active {
  include global;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  include global;
}
```

I have changed the file extension to `.scss`

[image: .scss extension]

Corrected the bundle reference in `BundleConfig.cs` file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/site.scss"
    ));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

When I open the file in browser the following error is appended at the top:

`/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(21,13): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found 'global'
(29,13): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found 'global'
 */`

> VS isn't recognizing it as a SASS file and making @mixins work, because...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is missing `@` before `include <mixin name>`.

```css
@mixin global {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  outline: none;
}
*:link,
*:focus,
*:visited,
*:hover,
*:active {
  @include global;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  @include global;
}
```

Compilation is [automatically done when the `.scss` file is saved](http://www.mattburkedev.com/using-sass-with-visual-studio-2013-essentials/) when [WebEssentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) is installed.

The compiled `___.min.Css` file is supposed to be referenced not `___.min.Scss`

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/site.css"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: A @mixin id needs a parentheses to define arguments just like functions in other languages. In this case you don't have any arguments but you still need it. Try to write it like this: `@mixin global()`. And you'll need a @ before import as well: `@include global();`.

Second, you need to process the .scss-file to a .css and import that.

Comment: How do you process a `.scss` file in VS?

Comment: I haven't used SASS in Visual Studio myself. It seems to be a little tricky but [here is a plugin that might work](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d)

Comment: Mixins only require parentheses if they take arguments.

Comment: Well look at that. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: @cimmanon How is a SASS file compiled in VS using WebEssentials?

Comment: @student Why are you pinging me for no reason?  Not everyone who views or comments on your question is able to answer it.

Comment: @cimmanon Hey man, relax! The reason was - I was just *guessing* that you could solve my problem. I'll take care in your case hereafter :)